# Asyncio & Discord.py - how to stop a command running on while True?

Tags: python, discord.py, python-asyncio

I have the following function which plays mp3 files on repeat. I'm trying to create a command that kills stops this function from running.

```
async def play(ctx):
    ...
    while True:
        player = voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(executable="C:\\FFmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe", source=file))
        await asyncio.sleep(2)
```

I tried the following:

```
async def stop(ctx):
    global stop_repeat
    channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
    if not channel:
        await ctx.send("You are not connected to a voice channel")
        return
    voice = get(bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    if voice and voice.is_connected():
        await voice.move_to(channel)
    else:
        voice = await channel.connect()

    try:
        voice.pause()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

But it doesn't do anything at all. In other words i need a way to stop the `while True`. I'm having an hard time solving this proble, so any kind of advice is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `while condition:` rather than `while True:`

Then, you can have the condition be an object with a boolean inside.

```
class BoolState:
    def __init__(self, state):
        self.state = state
    
    def __bool__(self):
        return self.state


doRepeat = BoolState(True)

while doRepeat:
    print("Hello World!")

# Call this to end the loop
doRepeat.state = False
```

Note that as I have implemented it here, you will have no way of stopping it. However, you are using async functions, so you can just edit the state of the `doRepeat` in your `stop` function.

Remember to make `doRepeat` global, outside of your `stop` function, or you might get an error when you try to call it a second time.

This is essentially making a class that functions as a mutable boolean. Booleans are not mutable in Python, but this way all you have to do is change the state of the variable the class contains.

Answer (score 2):

What else have you tried? Would something like this work?

```py
async def play(ctx):
    ...
    my_condition = True
    while my_condition:
        player = voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(executable="C:\\FFmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe", source=file))
        await asyncio.sleep(2)
        my_condition = await update_condition()
```

where `update_condition()` is an asynchronous coroutine (`async def update_condition()`) you define which returns `True` or `False` depending on if your condition is met.